# Is it possible to change a component name in a component designer in WinForms .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've created a component whose name I'd like to be able to change while editing in the component tray.
I've added a Designer action for a name property, but now I'm stuck.

Looking at the property grid, I can see that the name property is parenthesised, indicating that it's not a regular property.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to change the control's name? Got an example of why you need to do this? There might be a simpler solution rather than thinking along these lines.

Comment: My component is a skin\theme for an enhanced message box control. If I design a new skin from the tray, it would be nice to name it, say "Office Style", from the same place, without having to go to the property grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of a `Component` at design-time using `Component.Site.Name`. You should put the code in a try/catch block to handle exception when the name is duplicate.

**Code:**

When you implement a designer for your component, the man code for change the name of component at design time is:

```
this.Component.Site.Name = "SomeName";
```

Here is a full implementation of a component and a component designer. The component designer has a verb that is accessible when you right click on the component, also it's accessible from property grid in commands tray. When you click on `Rename` command, it sets the name of component to `SomeName`. It also shows an error message if there is a component with the same name. In a more realistic sample, you can override `ActionLists` to let the user enter a new name itself.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(MyComponentDesigner))]
public class MyComponent : Component
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyComponentDesigner : ComponentDesigner
{
    DesignerVerbCollection verbs;
    public MyComponentDesigner() : base() { }
    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (verbs == null)
            {
                verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();
                verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Rename", (s, e) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.Component.Site.Name = "SomeName";
                        this.RaiseComponentChanged(null, null, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var svc = ((IUIService)this.GetService(typeof(IUIService)));
                        svc.ShowError(ex);
                    }
                }));
            }
            return verbs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the properties are special in the Design Environment and you can only really set them via the Type Descriptor. This may be the case for the name, but it certainly is the case for things like Visible, Locked and Enabled. Perhaps this will give you something to look at for now.

```
SetHiddenValue(control, "Visible", false);
SetHiddenValue(control, "Locked", true);
SetHiddenValue(control, "Enabled", false);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the hidden value - these are held in the type descriptor properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">The control.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
    /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
    private static void SetHiddenValue(Control control, string name, object val)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control)[name];
        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            descriptor.SetValue(control, val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer shows a lack of understanding of OP's question and offers a solution that's inappropriate. Reza's answer is correct.