# Changing the Name of item using a CollectionEditor in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

For design-time support, I am implementing a `CollectionEditor` as follows:

```
class CustomCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    ...
    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        ...
        var propertyGrid = form.Controls.Find(
            PropertyGridComponentName, true).First() as PropertyGrid;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

which is attached to a custom control via the following manner:

```
[Editor(typeof(CustomCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
class CustomControl : Control
{
    ...
}
```

By overriding the `CreateCollectionForm()` method of the `CollectionEditor` class , I gain access to the `PropertyGrid` and am able to change properties of the selected item via accessing appropriate `PropertyDescriptor` instances.

However, setting the **`Name`** property does not seem to update the instance name within the collection editor.

If I try the following:

```
var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propertyGrid.SelectedObject)["Name"];
descriptor.SetValue(propertyGrid.SelectedObject, "instanceName");
```

the statement seems to execute, yet the *name* of the selected item within the property grid *does not change*.

Therefore, my question is, **how, if it at all possible, do I update the `Name` property of the selected item programatically?**

For clarity, I am trying to update from code what one would type in the **Name** field of the property grid as follows:

[image]

and again, all other properties (*e.g.*, "ForeColor", "Text", *etc.*) can be changed without issue using the above method; just the `Name` property is causing the difficulty.  I assume this is because `Name` is not a *"real"*  property.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Name)` property belongs to a `Component` and you can change name of selected object of property grid by casting selected object to [`Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) and setting its [`Site.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isite.name(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var component = propertyGrid.SelectedObject as Component;
if(component !=null )
{
    component.Site.Name = "SomeNewName";
    propertyGrid.Refresh();
}
```

You should put the code in try/catch block to handle the exception when there is a component with the same name.

Comment: One additional caveat, when using the `CollectionEditor`, while `Component.Site.Name = name` performs the actual renaming, an additional declaration `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propertyGrid.SelectedObject)["Name"] = name` is required for the `CollectionEditor` to "see" that the property was changed and thus update when it passes the collection back to the form or control which called it up.

Comment: In a `Designer`, you can use `this.RaiseComponentChanged(null, null, null);` It notifies the designer that the component has been changed. You may find my answer here useful: [Is it possible to change a component name in a component designer in WinForms .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35549872/3110834)

Comment: Yes, quite useful.  Thank-you!